# How to extract only Message from the system eventvwr

Tags: powershell, operating-systems, event-viewer

I am trying to extract only the Message from the system eventvwr for a specific ID, but when i try using the below command i am getting the entire mesaage which is very long to print or send over mail.

Need help in trimming the message or extract only some part of the message.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -InstanceId 12510 -Newest 1 | Select-Object -Property Message | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Which part are you trying to trim? If you are already able to extract the message, then what is the problem? How short should the message be? Based on what criteria?

Comment: There will be mesage in the tag called <message> </message> only that text need to be printed out

Answer (score 0):

Try it this to get the whole message

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 1).Message
# Results
<#
Windows Management Instrumentation Service subsystems initialized successfully
#>
```

You can parse this into objects to make it more readable if there is more data.

Now, sending this Out-GridView will be again, one long string. It does not have a text wrapping feature.

What I am showing is dumping this to the console (ISE/VSCode/CLI). So, if you want it all readable, then dump it to the console or push it out to Notepad or the like, or cover the text to an object and format as needed.

Here is another approach you can use to break this up for viewing. Remember EV data is just XML. So, just parse it:

```
$event         = Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -MaxEvents 1
[xml]$xmlEvent = $event.ToXml()
$xmlevent.Event.EventData.Data | 
Out-GridView
```

***Update as per your comment and my response to that***

Extracting text from between X and Y thing is a very common thing in all languages. This is not unique to PowerShell. Regular expressions (RegEx), is the q&d (Quick and Dirty) of getting this done. For example:

```
[regex]::matches( 'The Exchange web service request <message> GetAppManifests </message> succeeded.' , '(?<=<message>\s+)(.*?)(?=\s+</message>)' ).Value 
# Results
<#
GetAppManifests
#>
```

If the file is XML, JSON, then that is what the XML and JSON cmdlets are there for.

***Update as per your specific event ID comment***

Again, just an example - tweak as needed.

```
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Security";Id=4648} -MaxEvents 1 | 
ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    # create an ordered hashtable object to collect all data
    # add some information from the xml 'System' node first
    $evt = [ordered]@{
        EventDate = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
        Computer  = $eventXml.System.Computer
    }
    $eventXml.EventData.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object { $evt[$_.Name] = $_.'#text' }
    # output as PsCustomObject. This ensures the $result array can be written to CSV easily
    [PsCustomObject]$evt
}

# output to screen
$result
```

Comment: I can read all the data with the code I written,  but that is not what I am looking for, only the specific text in the message tag need to be displayed or printed

Comment: AS per what 'Reddy Lutonadio' said in the comments. YOu are not say what segment of the data you want. So, until you tell us we cannot help. However, the last sample code I gave would allow you to cherry-pick whatever you want.

Comment: In the eventvwr message we will have the message tag as mentioned,  just need to trim that data to send a mail

Comment: Did you try my code segment on your dataset to see the points from where you could extract data?  My sample produces an array of the message that you can pick the array element of choice, or you can just ***use RegEx Match*** to select all text between ***<message> </message>*** or the XML element ***<message> </message>***, which again should give you what you are after. Again, EV is just XML. So, using what I show in my last example, or using the***XML cmdlets, Get-Command -Name 'Select-Xml'   ---   Get-Help -Name 'Select-Xml' -Detail   Get-Help -Name 'Select-Xml' -Examples***

Comment: when i try the XML event i got the below error

**Method invocation failed because [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry] does not 
contain a method named 'ToXml'.**

Comment: If you are using the Get-EventLog cmdlet, then no that is not there and the XML parsing I am showing is using Get-WinEvent which is the newer cmdlet to use, not the old Get-EventLog.

Comment: How to get Particular event ID details using Get-winevent, with get-eventlog we can use -eventid for the ID which we can get

Comment: See my update for you.

Comment: Currently i am geeting error message for the eventid which i am looking is as below

Comment: **Error Message**
Timestamp: 9/9/2022 12:07:33 AM
**Message: <Exception><Message>Error occurred during synchronization: There was no endpoint listening at https://.org/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.</Message>**
<Source /><StackTrace /><ThreadId>11</ThreadId><InnerException>

I am looking for the output which is in bold from the above message so that it will be easy to print or send via mail instaed of the full error message

Comment: Just capture that data into a variable and use the RegEx I've already provided. You'll need to tweak it to get your message.